Can an unmanaged process (e.g. Microsoft Excel) load components targeting different .NET core/.NET runtimes?
I read a comment in a GitHub support request thread that triggered a question in my head about the possibility for an unmanaged process on a Windows machine to load multiple components targeting different runtimes (.NET core, .NET 5, .NET 6, etc.). Is there indeed a "hard limitation that different versions of the .NET core runtime cannot be loaded into a process"? Reading a subsequent post by the same person it seems that .NET framework components do not have this limitation and can coexist in the same process with a one or more components targeting the same .NET core/.NET runtime but this is not true for components targeting 2 or more different versions of .NET core/.NET. Why is that?

seems that .NET framework components do not have that's not the case. .NET Framework 4.x runtime versions are binary replacement that can't be downgraded. That means there's only one 4.x runtime on a single machine. Unless the application uses its own isolated runtime installation, the way SQL Server does. Even then though, there's only one runtime version.

Framework allows different CLR versions. There are only three: 1.x, 2.x, 4.x. And .NET Core only allows one version in total on top of that. @PanagiotisKanavos Side-by-side execution for Framework is a thing, albeit a rather Bad Idea, only for 2.x with 4.x, not for two minor builds of the same version.

That's not accurate. .NET Framework 1, 2 and 4 aren't just different versions, they're completely different binaries, saved in different locations. It's the same with .NET Core major versions. That's what allows running .NET Framework 2 and 4 applications side by side, or .NET Core 3 and 8 side by side.

In the case of Excel or any unmanaged application though, it's the application that hosts, initializes and starts the .NET environment. If the application was written to host different runtimes it could do so. None does so though, because there's no real reason, and hosting multiple environments is a real pain. Who's responsible for each managed object? How many garbage collectors should run? Do they communicate with each other or not?

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure I understand your first comment. Anyhow what I meant to say is that apparently components targeting .NET framework and a single version of .NET can concurrently be loaded by Excel while components targeting different versions of .NET cannot.

COM got short shrift in .NET in more than one way.  The "why" is hard to answer without being employed at Microsoft.  I'd guess somewhere between a concerted effort in 2012 to shed the troublesome Automation and there just not being a lot of employees around that still know COM internals and usage well.
